# How to call java constant variables from jsp expression language in Spring?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, weblogic, scriptlet

I've spent a day looking for the right solution, but no luck!
The question is that how to call java constant variables from jsp with el ${bean.objectName} for example. What is the best practice?

I wonder if this is doable, im quite new to Spring and jsp.

Constant class:

```
public class RNConstant {
     public static final String HELLO_WORLD = "Hello World again!";
     public static final String DEFAULT_LOCALE = "id_ID";
     public static final String CONTEXT_PATH_SOAP_SR = "soap.sr";
}
```

Expectation in jsp to be called with EL

```
 <p>${RNConstant.HELLO_WORLD}</p>
```

I could do this with scriptlet as below, but i could not get this working if it runs in weblogic. This works in apache tomcat v7 or v8

```
<%@ page import="static id.co.telkom.common.RNConstant.*" %>
 ...
 ...
<%= HELLO_WORLD %>
```

Error in weblogic

```
home.jsp:2:18: Syntax error on token "static", Identifier expected after this token
<%@ page import="static id.co.telkom.common.RNConstant.*" %>
             ^-------------------------------------^
home.jsp:11:19: HELLO_WORLD cannot be resolved
Hello world!  <%=HELLO_WORLD%>
                     ^--------^
```

java version: 1.6

pom.xml

```
 spring
 <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.2.8.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.springjs-version>2.0.5.RELEASE</org.springjs-version>
    <org.springws-version>2.2.1.RELEASE</org.springws-version>
    <org.springsecurity-version>3.2.3.RELEASE</org.springsecurity-version>
    <jackson-version>1.9.10</jackson-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
 </properties>
```

Scriplet issue was solved with below codes, and Content of RNConstant is still the same.

```
<%@ page import="id.co.telkom.common.RNConstant" %>
...
...
<%= RNConstant.HELLO_WORLD %>
```

Cheers,

Hendry

Comment: I am confused, can't you access them by using model.addAttribute("nameuwishinjsp",nameofvariableinjava); . Am I incorrect?

Comment: @WeareBorg yes we could do that, however, what im trying to achieve is that to create a constant class that could be called directly and globally from  .jsp files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep the import statement simple

```
<%@ page import="static id.co.telkom.common.RNConstant.*" %>
```

Remove ".*" after `RNConstant`. Also remove static word in the beginning.

```
<%@ page import="id.co.telkom.common.RNConstant" %>.
```

To call HELLO_WORLD constant use

```
<p>${RNConstant.HELLO_WORLD}</p> <p>${RNConstant.HELLO_WORLD}</p>
```

Comment: @JordiCastilla editted, should use scriplet tag to call constant class instead of EL.

Comment: @AdrianusHendry your question was how to reference constants using Expression Language. The answer given addresses a different issue and hence should not be accepted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Expectation in jsp to be called with EL

```
<p>${RNConstant.HELLO_WORLD}</p>
```

EL checks the bean and translates `HELLOWORLD` to `getHELLOWORLD()` because specs says that attributes must be accessed in this way, so you must create a `getter` or visibility for constants will be limited in jsp view:

```
public class RNConstant 
{    
    public final static String HELLO_WORLD = "Hello World again!";

    public static String getHELLO_WORLD() {
        return HELLO_WORLD;
    }   
}
```

If you can't create getters check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127328/java-constants-in-jsp)

Comment: hi, but the scriplet works in apache tomcat v8 server. i could not get that getter would be the cause

Comment: Keep the import statement simple <%@ page import="id.co.telkom.common.RNConstant" %>. Remove ".*" after RNConstant and also remove static word in the beginning.  To call HELLO_WORLD constant use <p>${RNConstant.HELLO_WORLD}</p> <p>${RNConstant.HELLO_WORLD}</p>

Comment: @gujralam hi, this does not solve the issue. The error gone, but value does not come up. No error message on the weblogic server log

Comment: @gujralam this should be posted as an answer

Comment: @gujralam Hi thanks, it works now, it has to be printed using scriplet tag as well such as <%= RNConstant.HELLO_WORLD %>
you should write it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks Adrianus. I have added that as a answer. Please accept the answer.