# Is it possible to use a global variable in Java to Jsp

Tags: java, jsp

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [accessing constants in JSP (without scriptlet)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122254/accessing-constants-in-jsp-without-scriptlet)
>   [Reference interface constant from EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732608/reference-interface-constant-from-el)

Hi,

I have a public or global variable res used in  a protected void function in Admin.java. Can I use this variable in another function login in index.jsp page within the same application. Is it possible?

I have tried using Admin.res in the function in one more class SemanticSearch.java. The value of res is easily retrieved but it is not so in the case if I need to use it in index.jsp. I have tried printed in index.jsp using alert but the value is not printed.

Please help,
Regards,
Archana

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2001072001&page=1) how to do that

Comment: The tutorial says to use javabean. But I am not able to understand how to use it for my program. My application has two files index.jsp and admin.java. In admin.java I have a public static variable res. This variable gets its value from another function in SemanticSearch.java. The value is populated in SemanticSearch.java and is send back to admin.java file (i.e. to a function). From here the value of res has to be passed to index.jsp. Please note the function in admin.java from which the variable res has to be passed is a void function and therefore cannot have (statement) return res.

Comment: I have checked the other related questions and in their answers I have understood I can use request.setAttribute and get....methods. I have tried using them as in:

Comment: public static String rest; declared in Admin.java file.Then in the -----protected void doGet method in Admin.java I have written: String res=semsearch.searchForUser(userName, password); System.out.println("The value of res been passed is "+res); request.setAttribute("rest", res);--------------------------/ when I try to print the value of rest here the value is null. The value in variable res is C Language which I have got from the function written in SemanticSearch.java file. Why do I get a null value here? Once this is acheived I need to get this value to be passed to index.jsp. Please help.