# How to concatenate a JSTL variable with JSP id?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

```
<%@attribute name="myid" required="true"%>
<input type="text" id="<%=it.java.class.utils.ParameterPortlet.%>${myid}" />
```

I want to concatenate `<%=java.class%>` with `${myid}` to get `it.java.class.utils.ParameterPortlet.myid`. But after deploying my project I get this error:

```
ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-86][PortletRequestDispatcherImpl:137] org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
```

In `it.java.class.utils.ParameterPortlet` I have `myClass.java` that contains a list of strings:

```
public final class myClass {
    public static final String INPUTNAMEID = "myname";
    public static final String INPUTCITYID = "mycity";
    public static final String INPUTID = "myid";
}
```

So what I want to do is to change dynamically the "myid" `<%=it.java.class.utils.ParameterPortlet.myid%>` using JSTL to `myinput, myselect, myid`, etc..

What I did wrong?
Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `<input type="text" id="<%=it.java.class.utils.ParametriPortlet.class%>${myid}" />`?

Comment: You may find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122254/accessing-constants-in-jsp-without-scriptlet uselful.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `class`, which will have its `toString` method invoked:

```
<input type="text" id="<%=it.java.class.utils.ParametriPortlet.class%>${myid}" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much Kevin. I tried but doesn't work. Please see my last edit to the question. Thank you!